# How execute curl with JSON on GitHub Actions

Tags: curl, github-actions

I'm trying to run this curl on GitHub Actions but I get error 500.

This is my curl structure.

```
on: 
 push:
  branches:
   - main
name: My project - CI
jobs:
 curl:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  - name: curl
  uses: wei/curl@v1
  with:
    args: -k -u MMiwNBRJKOqE4Ulom4h91638592985:0ffa995d8707ffbbc01a8b1013ad9fa9 --request POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"value1":"1","value2":"2","value3":"3","value4":"4"}' https://website.com/directory_path/
```

From Windows command prompt it works, but on gitHub Actions I get error 500.

```
/usr/bin/docker run --name b31b9e2fd97fe9742bdba23021bfc19c99b_65230d --label 294b31 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e INPUT_ARGS -e HOME -e GITHUB_JOB -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER -e GITHUB_RUN_ID -e GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER -e GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS -e GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_SERVER_URL -e GITHUB_API_URL -e GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL -e GITHUB_REF_NAME -e GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED -e GITHUB_REF_TYPE -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_ACTION_REF -e GITHUB_PATH -e GITHUB_ENV -e GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_ARCH -e RUNNER_NAME -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN -e ACTIONS_CACHE_URL -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/buidl_actions/buidl_actions":"/github/workspace" 294b31:b9e2fd97fe9742bdba23021bfc19c99b curl -k -u MMiwNBRJKOqE4Ulom4h91638592985:0ffa995d8707ffbbc01a8b1013ad9fa9 --request POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"value1":"1","value2":"2","value3":"3","value4":"4"}' https://website.com/directory_path/
```

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: curl
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 500

Comment: Are you sure `https://website.com/` is up and publicly available? You can use `-vvv` flag to get more details on `curl`.

Comment: Also, `curl` is available on ubuntu runner, so there's no need to use an action you can invoke it directly from shell.

Comment: have you been able to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, a solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: That's good to hear, can you please share how you solved it, so others with similar issue could also benefit?